# Changing menu type dynamically in ZURB Foundation

Tags: zurb-foundation

I have a HTML menu with `ul` and `li` tags and I want it to be either dropdown or drilldown type. Is there any way to reinitialize the `ul` tag with another type using Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From foundation docs: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/dropdown-menu.html

You can initialize your menu in javascript

```
var element = $('#myMenu')
var elem = new Foundation.Drilldown(element, options);
var elem = new Foundation.DropdownMenu(element, options);
```

Here's a fiddle showing how you can switch a menu between dropdown and drilldown: https://jsfiddle.net/genestd/8akhm8bn/

Note when initiation DropdownMenu after Drilldown, you need to remove the `invisible` class like this in the fiddle:

```
$("#mymenu>li>ul.invisible").removeClass("invisible");
```